# Internal Server Error (500) showing on sub-routes when running Django on server

Tags: django, hosting, vps, server-error

I'm hosting my Django application on a VPS and I'm using Django Rest Framework and the Django Admin Site.

Everything seemed working running fine (check the below image),

[image]
but when I try to click on my API's I'm redirected to a Server Error (500) page.

One thing to notice is that when I'm running the app locally on my machine everything is working fine.

Below is my `settings.py` if it can help in anyway:

```
Django settings for thepatron project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os
import django_heroku
import datetime
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Initialize environment variables
load_dotenv()

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
try:
    SECRET_KEY = str(os.getenv('SECRET_KEY'))
except KeyError as e:
    raise RuntimeError("Could not find a SECRET_KEY in environment") from e

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    # VPS
    '194.5.159.80',
    # the-patron
    'the-patron.com'
    # Heroku
    'https://the-patron-backend.herokuapp.com/',
    # Hostinger IP Address
    '141.136.43.2',
    # Home IP Address
    '127.0.0.1',
    # Local Frontend Port
    'localhost:4200',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'store.User'

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

# CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False

# CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
#     'http//:localhost:8000',
# )

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'django_filters',
    'store',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True  # If this is used then `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS` will not have any effect
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

ROOT_URLCONF = 'thepatron.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'thepatron.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    # Database settings to connect to hosted database 
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': str(os.getenv('DATABASE_NAME')),
        'USER': str(os.getenv('DATABASE_USER')),
        'PASSWORD': str(os.getenv('DATABASE_PASS')),
        'HOST': '141.136.43.2',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'sql_mode': 'traditional',
        }
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME':
        'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME':
        'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME':
        'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME':
        'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

if DEBUG:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'store/static/store'),
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/restframework'),
    ]
else:
    # The absolute path to the directory where collectstatic will collect static files for deployment.
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

# URL to use when referring to static files located in STATIC_ROOT.
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# MEDIA_ROOT is for server path to store files in the computer.
# This is where the backend loads media like images from
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/store/media')

# MEDIA_URL is the reference URL for browser to access the files over Http.
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage',
]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': [
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
        'rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':
    ('rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication', )
}

JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600),
}

# Activate Django-Heroku.
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Comment: Can you add the full traceback for the error from the logs?

Comment: A 500 error is a very generic "there was an exception" error.  It is not possible to answer this question without getting more information about what the error actually was.   That information can usually be located in the log files for the web server.

Comment: Should I get the logs of gunicorn or nginx in this case? @StephenOstermiller

Comment: @IainShelvington Where can I find these logs?

Comment: I'd check all the logs you have available.  Errors can end up in different log files depending on configuration.

Comment: I was able to know what the error was by changing DEBUG to True in settings.py.
The error was as below:
(1045, "Access denied for user 'None'@'194.5.159.80' (using password: YES)")
Note that when I wasn't able to login to the Django admin site using my credentials although both username and password where true!!!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

In settings.py

```
DEBUG = True
```